# Creating python nested dictionary from data frame columns and saving the result in a new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am working towards getting 3 columns from a DataFrame and creating a dictionary from them and saving it in a new DataFrame.

Here is the original DataFrame:

```
part_id    name exp_no  key value
1       Clips   58868   name    Charlie
1       Clips   58870   phone   123456789
1       Clips   58845   region  Ontario
2       Clips   58821   city    London
2       Clips   58832   country Chili
3       Nails   58869   postalcode  123456
3       Nails   58830   colour  red
```

I am using pandas but without much success and would really appreciate some help

## Creating new DataFrame and get only unique data in there

```
new_file = pd.DataFrame()
new_file = data_unique
for part_id in data.iterrows():
  if part_id in new_file:
```

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
This error indicates that DataFrame is not right choice for this kind of program. What other method would be more suitable?

This is how the final result must look - One record per part_number

```
part_id name    exp_no  key value   exp_key_value
1       clips   58868   name    Charlie {"attributes": 
[{"exp_no":"58868", "key":"name", "value":"Charlie"}, 
{"exp_no":"58870", "key":"phone", "value":"123456789"}, 
{"exp_no":"58845", "key":"region", "value":"Ontario"} ] } 
2       clips   58821   city    London  {"attributes": 
[{"exp_no":"58821", "key":"city", "value":"London"}, 
{"exp_no":"58832", "key":"country", "value":"Chili"} ] }
3   nails   58869   postal  12345   {"attributes": 
[{"exp_no":"58869", "key":"postal", "value":"12345"}, 
{"exp_no":"58830", "key":"colour", "value":"red"} ] }
```

Comment: use drop_duplicates and give the subset you want to remove duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({"part_id":[1,1,1,2,2,3,3],
               "name":['Clips', 'Clips' , 'Clips' , 'Clips', 'Clips', 'Nails', 'Nails'], 
               "exp_no": [58868, 58869, 58860, 58861, 588682, 58863, 58864], 
               "key":['name', 'phone', 'region','city', 'country', 'postalcode', 'colour'], 
              "value": ['Charlie', '123456789', 'Ontario', 'London','Chili', '123456', 'red']})

   # create the dictonary for each row
   def create_dic(row):
     dict ={}
     dict['exp_no'] = row['exp_no']
     dict['key'] = row['exp_no']
     dict['value'] = row['exp_no']
     return dict

   df['exp_key_value'] = df.apply(create_dic, axis=1)

   df_dropped = df.drop_duplicates(subset= 'part_id',  keep ='first')

   final =[]
   dict = {}

   for i, part in enumerate(df['part_id'].unique()):
     dict['attribute'] =df[df['part_id']==part]['exp_key_value'].tolist()
     final.append(dict)

   df_dropped['exp_key_value'] = final
```

Comment: Thank you, Keshav. Just got 'TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment' - dict['attribute'] =df[df['part_id']==part]['exp_key_value'].tolist()

Comment: you got this error for running the exact same above code?

Comment: Yes, running it on Jupyter Notebook on Python 3

Comment: sorry my bad, I missed a line of code, of initializing `dict = {}`. Made edit above!